# Strong sustained magnetic field causes fires in Sicilian town. How can anyone generate this?

Tags: electromagnetism

I am just a dumb physician. Didn't go into physics because I suck at math. 
Anyway, I follow the field ofphysics with interest, but I get lost when it comes to calculus & beyond. Here is a question that begs a logical answer:

In 2010, there were a series of fires in a city in Northerbpn Sicily, Cannetto di Caronnia. Toasters started catching fires, electrical junctions boxes would start burning etc. Then spring mattresses started catching fire... (Not kidding, look it up, it was repported by major networks & press!). The people blamed the electrical company, lawsuits were filed etc. The electrical company after not finding anything wrong with its network, out of frustration physically disconnected power to the city. Generators were provided. These too would periodically catch fire as well... People were moved out & scientists from Italy, Germany (Max Plank institute) & a third one were dispatched to the site. All power was disconnected. Using battery powered spectrum analyzer  & some helical antennas voltmeters & other simple equipment they setup camp.  On several occasions during 5 days they detected enormous periodic (minutes long) magnetic fields that coincided with disconnected street lights to turn on, car alarms went off, car electonic locks were opening & closing. So a tremendous magnetic field coming from the north (sea or southern tip of Italy).  This made the news, & about 2 days later, no more. It totally stopped.  Magma effect was ruled out, final report : 14 Tera-Joules would have been needed to create this field. How? Not a pulse, a sustained field!

Comment: My impression is the phenomena you mention do not have a generally accepted explanation. As for "tremendous magnetic field", until you give a reference, there is nothing to discuss.

Comment: These phenomena date back to 2005. According to wikipedia (http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canneto_(Caronia)) an international group of scientists was created (Gruppo Interistituzionale per l'Osservazione dei Fenomeni) to investigate the phenomenon. The conclusion was that it had artificial causes, and paranormal activity or natural causes were ruled out. As far as I know, apart from this official report, there are only conspiracy theories, such as the one that links these phenomena to the presence of US military bases in Sicily with alleged secret experiments or stuff along these lines.

Comment: The question is too vaguely formulated to be answerable using the laws of physics.

Comment: "Strong sustained magnetic field" is one of the hypothesis investigated, but the investigation didn't look like seriously pushed forward. If there was a strong magnetic field its lines would have been identified and an origin should have been located (with 4 spaced mesure points).

Comment: An official report is conspiracy theory that is signed by an official who didn't have anything better to do that day. Get back to us when you have a peer reviewed scientific paper.